# Sqlite3 activerecord :order => "time DESC" doesn't sort

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, reserved-words

rails 2.3.4, sqlite3

I'm trying this

> Production.find(:all, :conditions => ["time > ?",
> start_time.utc], :order => "time DESC",
> :limit => 100)

The *condition* works perfectly, but I'm having problems with the *:order => time DESC*.

By chance, I discovered that it worked at Heroku (testing with heroku console), which runs PostgreSQL. However, locally, using sqlite3, **new entries** will be sorted after old ones, no matter what I set *time* to. Like this (*output has been manually stripped*): second entry is new:

> Production id: 2053939460, time: "2010-04-24 23:00:04", created_at: "2010-04-24 23:00:05"
>
> Production id: 2053939532, time: "2010-04-25 10:00:00", created_at: "2010-04-27 05:58:30"
>
> Production id: 2053939461, time: "2010-04-25 00:00:04", created_at: "2010-04-25 00:00:04"
>
> Production id: 2053939463, time: "2010-04-25 01:00:04", created_at: "2010-04-25 01:00:04"

Seems like it sorts on the primary key, *id*, not *time*. Note that the query works fine on heroku, returning a correctly ordered list! I like sqlite, it's so KISS, I hope you can help me...

Any suggestions?

---

UPDATE/SOLVED:
*time* is a reserved sqlite3 keyword (*date*, amongst others, is too). This is why `:order => 'time DESC'` works in PostgreSQL ([*non-reserved keyword*](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/sql-keywords-appendix.html)), but not in sqlite3. The solution is to avoid having sqlite3 keywords as column names if you ever intend to sort on them. **Renaming solves the problem.**

I've tested with the standard rails pattern *updated_at* and *created_at*, which works perfectly.

I still prefer sqlite3 in development, it's so simple and smooth to work with, copy the database and send to your partner. Thanks to @newtover !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is usually a bad idea to use reserved words without surrounding quotes. `time` is a built-in function in SQLite, try using the following instead and better get rid of the ambiguity in the first place:

```
Production.find(:all,
                :conditions => ["`time` > ?", start_time.utc],
                :order => "`time` DESC",
                :limit => 100)
```

**UPD**: The problem seems to have appeared on SO:

[Rails Active Record find(:all, :order => ) issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/742700/rails-active-record-findall-order-issue)

Comment: Ah, I'm using a reserved word! Stupid me.. It doesn't seem to work with the neither ` or ' but I've tested you're right, using updated_at instead of time. I guess I'll have to rename the column then?

Comment: It's too sad I can't give you a vote, the answer was quick and spot on! You should get extra points, votes, repu or whatever, for answering people who you know cannot upvote you :) So, thank you!

Comment: @Ole Morten Amundsen: it seems like your problem is known. Try to order by `strftime('%s', updated) DESC`

Comment: What I read of that SO the answers are summarized like this:

**1.** Switching to another database solves the problem (To me, that's not solving) 

**2.** *date* is poorly handled in sqlite3. (date is also reserved, right? So they probably have the same problem as I, with *time*)

It doesn't seem to help with anything, as long as my 
**column name = reserved keyword** 
. Could not make it work with *strftime* either.  
** But to me, avoiding reserved words is a real solution ** :)

Comment: @Ole Morten Amundsen: unfortunatelly the problem is not with sqlite3, but with the connector to the sqlite in ruby. Since I have never coded ruby, I can not play with the example myself. Have you tried ordering by INT or TEXT fields? Can you try to sort by an expression? Try sorting by julianday(updated) which returns a number. Try issuing the statement with sqlite console directly or with syntax described here: http://sqlite-ruby.rubyforge.org/sqlite3/faq.html. The problem might be in the ORM solution yoo use.

Comment: I'm running PostgreSQL at the server and sqlite3 in dev. I wouldn't recommend using the DB-specific commands as in the examples of the link you provided. Note that I can order by anything, ints, texts **and time/dates**, it's only a problem when I've named the *column time*. I see you write *updated*, you mean the column name, which should be *time*, right? I have a column *updated_at* too, which works perfectly fine with the ordering. And yes, the problem may that of the ORM, ActiveRecord or the sqlite3-ruby connector. I'll rename the column, as I know that works. Thanks @newtover !

Comment: Should work with double quotes around the keywords; that's the SQL standard way of making a reserved word safe (and SQLite adheres to the standard here). Don't know how you pass that through from Ruby…