# Order by time of day and regardless of date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a Schedule model with attributes Day and Time. Time is of datatype time.

I have data i.e.

> Monday / 2014-04-26 15:00:00.000000
>
> Monday / 2014-04-25 16:30:00.000000

In my controller I have `@schedule = Schedule.all(:order => 'Day, Time')`

Right now it is ordering by date, how do I order by time regardless of date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a SQLite3 Ruby connector issue. Works fine on Postgres.

Looks like SQLite does not have a native understanding of the Time datatype as stated here: [Rails Active Record find(:all, :order => ) issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/742700/rails-active-record-findall-order-issue) and here: http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

Renaming the attribute from `time` to i.e. `class_time` did not solve the problem as recommended here: [Sqlite3 activerecord :order => "time DESC" doesn't sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2719941/sqlite3-activerecord-order-time-desc-doesnt-sort)

Answer (score 4):

If you're using Postgres you can use

```
@schedule = Schedule.all.order('date_time_field::time').
```

If you're on Mysql I think it's something like

```
DATE_FORMAT(colName,'%H:%i:%s') TIMEONLY
```

Sqlite

```
@schedule = Schedule.all.order('time(date_time_field)')
```